# Auto Increase in PHP for HTML Table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to make a results table.

Here is a image of what the table looks like so far:

[image: img]

```
<?php
        $row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 5");
        while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%" align="center"><?php $rank=1; echo $rank;?></td>
            <td width="15%" align="center"><img src="/pictures/<?php echo $sql['Picture']; ?>.png" height="50%"></td>
            <td width="7%" align="center"><?php echo $sql['Votes']; ?></td>
        </tr>
              <?php } ?>
```

That is the code so far. I am trying to make it so the rank will auto increase. By the way, the rank is not coming from the database, but i just want it to start at 1 then increase. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 5");

    $rank = 0; // default rank
    while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($row))
    {
        $rank += 1; // increase
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%" align="center"><?php echo $rank;?></td>
            <td width="15%" align="center"><img src="/pictures/<?php echo $sql['Picture']; ?>.png" height="50%"></td>
            <td width="7%" align="center"><?php echo $sql['Votes']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realize that it would be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the $rank variable is declared in the while loop

```
<td width="5%" align="center"><?php $rank=1; echo $rank; //this line ?></td>
```

So you need to move it out of the loop, because it will set to 1 again when the loop continue (that why is always display 1)

To fixed the problem you should do this

```
<?php
    $row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 5");
    $rank = 1; // declare rank here
    while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%" align="center"><?php echo $rank++; // increase rank by 1 each times the loop run ?></td>
        <td width="15%" align="center"><img src="/pictures/<?php echo $sql['Picture']; ?>.png" height="50%"></td>
        <td width="7%" align="center"><?php echo $sql['Votes']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this help!